# Runtime error 1004 when using Pastespecial with sourcetheme

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste the copied data into my worksheet by using pastespecial. It works fine but if I want to keep the existing format by adding 
Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme I get a

> runtime error 1004

. Can anyone help? Here's an extract:

```
Sub Zielerreichung_TPG124_Aktualisieren()
        Dim status
        Dim status2
        Dim Anz_Zeilen As Integer
        Dim Fehlerstatus As Boolean
        Dim Bereich As Range
        Dim ReportDatei As Workbook

    Dim RohDatei As Workbook
    Dim Pfad As String

    'Beschleunigungen für Operationen
    status = Application.Calculation
    status2 = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.Calculation = xlManual      'Automatische Berechung aus
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      'Screenupdating aus
    Fehlerstatus = Application.DisplayAlerts

    ActiveSheet.Rows(10 & ":" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).Delete

    Set ReportDatei = ActiveWorkbook
    Pfad = ReportDatei.Path

    'Öffne Rohdatei -> Achtung: Argument True (Sonst keine CSV Auswertung möglich)
    Workbooks.Open (Pfad & "\ZETPG124.xlsm")
    Set RohDatei = ActiveWorkbook

    'Doppelte & Irrelevante Zeilen löschen
    Rows("1:9").Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'Daten kopieren
    Anz_Zeilen = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Bereich = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Anz_Zeilen, 30))
    Bereich.Select
    Bereich.Copy

    'Rohdatei schließen
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    RohDatei.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Fehlerstatus

    'Warten vor dem Einfügen
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'Werte einfügen;
```

> ```
>     Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
> ```

Comment: Have you tried pasting before closing the source? Isn't Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme pretty much the same as .copy destination:=target?

Comment: @Jeeped Tried closing the source after pasting. Works now. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme option to the [range.PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) method, you cannot close the source before completing the copy and paste operation.

Just shift the following code line,

```
Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
```

... above this section,

```
'Rohdatei schließen
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
RohDatei.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = Fehlerstatus
```

... making sure that you are providing a proper parent workbook/worksheet parent reference.